# Sinatra/ActiveRecord + Heroku generating errors

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, configuration, heroku, sinatra

**SCENARIO:**
I'm using Sinatra + Sinatra/Active Record + SQLite3 for my local development. I am aware that when I push to Heroku that it uses Postgresql. Which is fine because I am using active record and I should have no problem.

**APP.RB File**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'

configure :development do
  set :database, 'sqlite://development.db'
end

configure :test do
  set :database, 'sqlite://test.db'
end

configure :production do
  db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/mydb')

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
    :host     => db.host,
    :username => db.user,
    :password => db.password,
    :database => db.path[1..-1],
    :encoding => 'utf8'
  )
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

end

get '/' do
  @test = Picture.find(:all)
  erb :index
end
```

**ERRORS**
When I try `heroku rake db:migrate` I get the following error...

```
DEBUG -- : NoMethodError: undefined method `values' for #<PGresult:0x00000002b24d08>: SHOW client_min_messages   

DEBUG -- : PGError: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "client_min_messages": ""
```

Then I thought ok no worries I'll try this heroku feature of pushing the data from my local sqlite3 `development.db` into my heroku production db. So I did `heroku push:db sqlite://development.db`  and **success the data is in.**

I then restarted the app and pushed further commits but I CANNOT access anything to do with ActiveRecord. If I make a basic query of `Picture.find(:all)` I get the same `DEBUG` error.

Is my `configure :production` messing me up?
Any recommendations?

Comment: "I am using active record and I should have no problem." You clearly haven't been reading the heroku questions on SO. You're a lot better off installing and developing against PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yeah starting to sound like I'm going to have to do this. Hoping not too learn another SQL language.

Comment: SQL is SQL. But SQLite isn't SQL. (And MySQL isn't either. Not yet.)

Comment: @Catcall: Does anyone actually implement the whole standard? You're dead on about the "I should have no problem" bit though.

Comment: Not to sound too naive BUT are there really huge issues with ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL? Is it that ActiveRecord is not that compatible with PostgreSQL? If you look at my code sample above I'm just doing a Picture.find(:all) and I'm getting errors with PostgreSQL, but with MySQL or SQLite it runs fine.

Comment: @muistooshort: AFAIK, only Ocelot implements all of SQL92. But SQLite and MySQL stray so far from the standards that I don't use them unless you point a gun at my head. (My main issues . . . SQLite: data types. MySQL: CHECK constraints and indeterminate GROUP BY.)

Comment: AR and PostgreSQL get along just fine, lots of Rails apps use PostgreSQL (including some of mine) without issue.

Answer (score 1):

You somehow manage to set the configuration parameter `client_min_messages` to an empty string.

The manual informs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN):

> Valid values are DEBUG5, DEBUG4, DEBUG3, DEBUG2, DEBUG1, LOG, NOTICE,
>   WARNING, ERROR, FATAL, and PANIC

You can set this parameter in `postgresql.conf` or any time in your session with:

```
SET client_min_messages = WARNING;
```

To reset it to the default defined in `postgresql.conf`:

```
RESET client_min_messages;
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know how I actually did that? I was just wondering if my application is even talking to the production DB on Heroku based on my settings.